# Parse date from JSON

Tags: android

I want to display the current time and data ,data is display right but time display wrong please help me where I am wrong, this is my code :

```
private String getDateFromJson(String dateString)
    {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            Date d1 = new Date();
            String dayOfTheWeek;
            dayOfTheWeek = sdf.format(d1);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            String ackwardRipOff = dateString.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");
            ackwardRipOff = ackwardRipOff.replace("+0000", "");
            Long timeInMillis = Long.valueOf(ackwardRipOff);
            calendar.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillis);


            System.out.println(calendar.getTime().toGMTString());
            String date = calendar.getTime().toGMTString();
            String time = date.split(" ")[3];
            SimpleDateFormat f1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            Date d = f1.parse(time);
            SimpleDateFormat f2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
            String timeString = f2.format(d).toLowerCase();
            String displayString = StringUtils.join(date.split(" ")[0], " ", date.split(" ")[1]," ", timeString);
            return displayString;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to give an example of the input, the output you're expecting, and the output you're actually getting.

Comment: Show format of date you are receiving from server and specify output format also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.It will help.

```
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

    Date date = new Date();
    String valnow = dateFormat.format(date);
    String data[] = valnow.split(" ");
    String presentdate = data[0];
    String presenttime = data[1];
```